# Block JSON access over the net

Tags: security

One of my websites scan by a security firm and came up with below to block
"http://domain.com/wp-includes/sodium_compat/composer.json" access over the internet. I've tried few plugins but none of them work, does anyone know how to block similar files display JSON on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to proceed: 
1) Use the `.htaccess` file to exclude the folder from begin listed
2) Exclude the `json` files from crawlers scan by adding them inside the `robots.txt` file.

Comment: Those been already implemented, but still, I can see JSON echo out by executing the above URL.

Answer (score 0):

I've change file permission, so It'll read-only by a system not to display to the public. I had assistance from my hosting provider.